# Draw UIImage with transformations in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, graphics, drawing

I have some transformable UIImageViews (decorates on a photo), which user can drag, pinch and rotate. After editing, I want the app to generate the final image. How can I draw the UIImageViews with their transform property considered.

My first solution is using `renderInContext`, but it can only generate a 320x480 image. Can I generate an image with any resolution?

Then I use code as follows:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(640.0f, 896.0f));
CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

UIImage *backgroundImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fittingBackground" ofType:@"jpg"]];
[backgroundImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 640.0f, 896.0f)];

CGContextSaveGState(currentContext);
CGContextConcatCTM(currentContext, self.photoImageView.transform);
CGRect photoFrame = self.photoImageView.frame;
[self.photoImageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(photoFrame.origin.x * 2, photoFrame.origin.y * 2, photoFrame.size.width * 2, photoFrame.size.height * 2)];
CGContextRestoreGState(currentContext);

CGContextSaveGState(currentContext);
CGContextConcatCTM(currentContext, self.productImageView.transform);
CGRect productFrame = self.productImageView.frame;
[self.productImageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(productFrame.origin.x * 2, productFrame.origin.y * 2, productFrame.size.width * 2, productFrame.size.height * 2)];
CGContextRestoreGState(currentContext);

UIImage *resultImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGBitmapContextCreateImage(currentContext)];

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

However, the result seems to be weird. And I've logged the frame, bounds and center. I don't know which `Rect` should I use in `drawInRect` after applying transform?

Comment: I use renderInContext in my app - it's not limited to the 320x480 resolution that you state...

Comment: I mean if my view is 320x480, then the result image is 320x480. Can I enlarge it to 640x960? Should I keep a larger copy of the view in the background?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
-(void)drawBackgroundInLayer:(CALayer*)destinationLayer {

    CGFloat scaledFactor = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    CGRect layerFrame = destinationLayer.frame;
    CGRect scaledRect = CGRectMake(layerFrame.origin.x, 
                                   layerFrame.origin.y, 
                                   (layerFrame.size.width)*scaledFactor, 
                                   (layerFrame.size.height)*scaledFactor);

    // Get the size and do some drawings
    CGSize sizeBack = CGSizeMake(layerFrame.size.width*scaledFactor, layerFrame.size.height*scaledFactor);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(sizeBack);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0., 0., 0., 1.);
    drawBorder(context, scaledRect);

    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    if (destinationLayer) {
        [destinationLayer setContents:(id)img.CGImage];
    }
}
```

The most important lines are 
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(sizeBack);
 UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

Comment: This code is from my personal projects, I was just trying to show you that you can generate custom size UIImage with CoreGraphics. Try using  this UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(sizeBack); UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); in your code.

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question is not clear enough. I mean after applying transforms, which rect (size and origin) should I use to draw transformed images.

Comment: Ok, I didn't understand that. You should do some computation to get the size. Or maybe by using CGBitmapContextGetHeight and CGBitmapContextGetWidth

Comment: Not really, I'm still not sure which CGRect should I draw in, after transforming.

Comment: Try with this one CGRectMake(0.,0.,CGBitmapContextGetWidth(context),CGBitmapContextGetHeight(context));